# calculate price based on price table

Tags: javascript, html, json

i want to create a price calculator FORM that print total price based on price table.
but there are too many price variations.

[image: this is the price table image].

as in the image checking on by one
like this:

```
if(type="type1" && size="22" && method="method1" && width=="150mm"){
totalPrice = 120;
}
```

is difficult.

is there a another way to do these kind of calculation like put data into JSON array and iterate through it to get the price.

[this codepen Example](https://codepen.io/sj-jay/pen/OJwJMBr)

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` or `===` is comparison

Comment: Related: [How can I simplify the code for multiple nested if else statements](/q/13525515/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a database object and store all the data in such a format that it can be retrieved based on the input property.

use this analogy:

```js
const database = {
 "type1": {
    "20ft": {
        "method1": {
            "150mm": "125$",
            "200mm": "132$",
            "250mm": "142$"
        },
        "method2": {
            ...
        },
        "method3": {
            ...
        }
    },
    "21ft": {
     ...
    }
 },
 "type2": {
    ...
 }
}

// When you want to fetch the answer use call the variable like this
const answer = database?.["type1"]?.["20ft"]?.["method1"]?.["150mm"] || null;
```

Comment: Thank you for the Answer.. i was also tying to do something like this before. but could not write the call function with multiple variables . this will perfectly do the job.  thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This method is possible using array filter and map

save as `get-price.js`

```js
const data = [
{
    "type": "type1",
    "size": "20ft",
    "length": "150mm",
    "method": "method1",
    "price": "125$"
},
{
    "type": "type1",
    "size": "20ft",
    "length": "150mm",
    "method": "method2",
    "price": "152$"
},
{
    "type": "type1",
    "size": "20ft",
    "length": "150mm",
    "method": "method3",
    "price": "170$"
},
{
    "type": "type1",
    "size": "20ft",
    "length": "200mm",
    "method": "method1",
    "price": "132$"
},
{
    "type": "type1",
    "size": "20ft",
    "length": "200mm",
    "method": "method2",
    "price": "152$"
},
{
    "type": "type1",
    "size": "20ft",
    "length": "200mm",
    "method": "method3",
    "price": "212$"
},
{
    "type": "type1",
    "size": "20ft",
    "length": "250mm",
    "method": "method1",
    "price": "142$"
},
{
    "type": "type1",
    "size": "20ft",
    "length": "250mm",
    "method": "method2",
    "price": "182$"
},
{
    "type": "type1",
    "size": "20ft",
    "length": "250mm",
    "method": "method3",
    "price": "112$"
}
]

const getPrice = (type, size, length, method) => {
return (data
    // filter matched condition
    .filter(el => {
        return el.type == type &&
        el.size == size &&
        el.length == length &&
        el.method == method
    })
    // map return price and first item of array
    .map (el => {
        return el.price
    })[0])
}

console.log(getPrice('type1', '20ft', '150mm', 'method3'))
console.log(getPrice('type1', '20ft', '150mm', 'method1'))
console.log(getPrice('type1', '20ft', '250mm', 'method2'))
```

Result

```
$node get-price.js

170$
125$
182$
```

Comment: Thank you for the Answer.. this method also perfectly do the job. but data array will have 360 objects. using filter and map also gives me another way.  thanks again

Comment: No problem, I also learn your table usage case.